# Relating classical rational points on projective varieties to modern ones

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Lots of questions about rational points on this site address the relationship between classical and modern notions of rational points on affine varieties/schemes. However, I can't find an explicit description for projective varieties. A (classical) rational point on a projective variety embedded in projective space is just a rational point of the ambient space that happens to solve the equations defining the variety. Is there an analog of this for the modern view of rational points as morphisms, such as for $R$-rational points where $R$ is a ring? Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: A rational point in modern language is just a map from $Spec k$ to the (projective) variety where $k$ is the base field.

Comment: I would start from $F$ the function field of the variety $X$ over $k$ and $O_X(U_j),F = Frac(O_X(U_j))$ a few subrings finitely generated as $k$-algebra and whose localization at maximal ideals agree ($O_X(U_j)_{m_j} = O_X(U_i)_{m_i}$ or $O_X(U_j)_{m_j}O_X(U_i)_{m_i}=F$). If $O_X(U_j)/m_j \cong k$ then $m_j$ is a $k$-rational closed point, and it corresponds to a point $\in X(k)$.